# requiredif struts validator to check two fields based on condition

Tags: struts, validation, struts-validation

I am trying to validate two fields one is a number and other is an url. At least one of this field has to have a valid value. If the number field has value and it is valid number or if the url field is present and it is a valid url the validation is passed.

I am using "requiredif" and "mask" to check this. The below is the example of the number checking,

```
<field property="nombre"
                 depends="requiredif,mask">
              <msg
                name="mask"
                key="errors.nombre"/>
                    <arg0 key="nombre"/>

              <msg
                name="requiredif"
                key="errors.validateNombreUrl"/>
                    <arg0 key="nombre"/>

              <var>
                <var-name>mask</var-name>
                <var-value>${nombre}</var-value>
              </var>

              <var>
                <var-name>url</var-name>
                <var-value>((url == null) and (*this* == null))</var-value>
              </var>
          </field>
```

In this similar manner, I am checking for the url field as well. But I see the validator validates both the field and shows up error such that BOTH fields are mandatory. How do I make it as a OR condition? I am not sure if the expression in the var value is right for requiredif, because I kind of found it works only for validwhen(which I can't use due to version issues). How do I validated these two fields on a OR condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what Struts version you're using, but requiredif has been deprecated since... a long time. [You should be using validwhen, described here](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/userGuide/dev_validator.html#validwhen). There is an example of what you want.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. Now I am using something like this
<var>
<var-name>test</var-name>
<var-value>((url == null) and (*this* != null))</var-value>
</var>

But this is throwing error when the url is null and the nombre field is a valid number :( Is there something wrong with the conditions?

Comment: I don't know; can't see the rest of the validation config.